# how to separate form data and file field

Tags: react-admin

I have a product form:

```
<Create {...this.props}>
    <SimpleForm defaultValue={postDefaultValue}>
        <TextInput source="productName" />
        <ReferenceInput label="Category" source="categoryId" reference="categories">
            <SelectInput optionText="categoryName" />
        </ReferenceInput>
        <TextInput source="price" label="Price"/>
        <ImageInput source="pic" label="Related pictures" accept="image/*">
            <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
        </ImageInput>
    </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```

at BE side, I have 2 apis:

one is for saving product info and return generated product id to FE, accept a json body(from the form):

```
    {
      "productName": "test",
      "price": 10.99,
      "categoryId": 1
    }
```

one is for saving the image, the product id should be interrelated.

so how can I work like this? what should I do with my dataProvider?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You may set-up two providers, one for each API. Then, in the data provider (the one you provide to the Admin), for the specific case of creating a post, you chain both call.

```
const mainProvider = restServerProvider('url-main-api');
const imgProvider = restServerProvider('url-img-api');

const dataProvider = {
  ...mainProvider,

  create: (resource, params) => mainProvider.create(resource, params)
    .then((results) => {
      if (resource === 'posts') {
        const { id } =  results.data; // depends on your API
        return imgProvider.create('posts', { data: { file: params.pic, id } });
      }
      return Promise.resolve();
    }),
}
```

You may need first to surcharge the imgProvider too, to handle the file upload, [see documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#extending-a-data-provider-example-of-file-upload) :

```
const imgProvider = {
  ...restServerProvider('url-img-api'),

  create: (resource, params) => {
    // see file upload example in the documentation
  }  
};
```